# JPA (hibernate) perform MySQL Fulltext select

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, full-text-search

**[What I need]**

MySQL Fulltext search funtionality like the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(200),
isbn VARCHAR(50),
year INT,
FULLTEXT (title)
);

INSERT INTO books (title,isbn,year) VALUES
('MySQL Tricks','1223', 2000),
('How To Use MySQL Well','234g2', 2010),
('Optimizing MySQL','125632', 2012),
('1001 MySQL Tricks','12312', 2015);

SELECT * FROM books
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tricks' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

RESULT:

```
MySQL Tricks  1223  2000

1001 MySQL Tricks  12312  2015
```

**[What I have]**

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private String title;
  private String isbn;
  private int year;


  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
  public String getTitle() {
      return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
  }
  public String getIsbn() {
      return isbn;
  }
  public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
      this.isbn = isbn;
  }
  public int getYear() {
      return year;
  }
  public void setYear(int year) {
      this.year = year;
  }
}
```

Handler:

```
@Singleton
public class BooksHandler {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Book createBook(String title, String isbn, int year) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle(title);
    book.setIsbn(isbn);book.setYear(year);
    em.persist(book);
    return book;
}

public List<Book> find(String titel){
    //replace with fulltext search
    String queryStr = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title LIKE :title";
    Query q = em.createQuery(queryStr, Book.class);
    q.setParameter("title", "%"+titel+"%");
    return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

How can I change what I have to achieve what I need ?

I want to perform MySQL fulltext search, from JPA (hibernate). I already know, this can be achieved using NativeQuery. But how do I need to change my Entity declaration, so that 'title' is recognized as FULLETXT.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After using hibernate, my Entity ('books') is generated in the database with the Entity class fields as columns (id, title, isbn, year). Title column is a varchar(255).

I manually exceuted following sql query in database:

```
ALTER TABLE books ADD FULLTEXT(title);
```

to make 'title' column FULLTEXT.

Then changed BooksHandler method find():

```
public List<Book> find(String titel){
    String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('"+titel+"' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);";
    Query nq = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr, Book.class);
    return nq.getResultList();
}
```

This solution works. But it is not optimal, because I had to alter 'title' by hand in the database.

**2. EDIT**

What I did based on the answer(vladwoguer) below:

added to persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="update.sql"/>
```

and made sure this line is set to 'create' (will not work with 'update'):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

And created 'update.sql' like mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  hibernate.cfg.xml add this line:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">update.sql</property>
```

On your update.sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `books_title_ft_index` (`title`);
```

Comment: Where do I find this file ? I only see the persistence.xml file

Comment: Add the line on your persistence.xml  and will have the same effect.

Comment: Ok my persitence.xml file location is: eclipse-workspace\projetName\src\main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml, where should the 'update.sql' file be placed ?

Comment: src/main/resources if it's a maven project